# How does one obtain the expansion of $e^{-x^2}$ in a power series?

Tags: calculus, power-series, exponentiation

So I know that the Power Series $y = \displaystyle\sum_{m=0}^\infty\displaystyle\frac{(-1)^m}{m!} x^{2m}$ is equivalent to $e^{-x^2}$.  Could someone show me why this is?

Comment: Take the power series of $e^w$, and plug in $w = -x^2$. Do you see how that works?

Comment: After posting $15$ questions, maybe its time to learn to use Tex - http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I'll add that you *can* plug in $w = -x^2$ because the infinite power series for $e^x$ is exactly equal to $e^x$ for all $x$.

Comment: Sorry to have upset you @Belgi.  I will be sure to familiarize myself better.

Answer (score 2):

You know that:

$$e^x=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\displaystyle\frac{x^n}{n!}$$

is a valid equation for every $-\infty<x<\infty$. For every $x\in \mathbb{R}$ we know that $\infty<-x^2\leq 0$ then if we replace $x$ by $-x^2$ in the equation above we get

$$e^{-x^2}=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\displaystyle\frac{(-1)^n x^{2n}}{n!}$$

which is valid for every $x\in \mathbb{R}$.